# How to remove ad script from wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

Every time I open my wordpress site, it has automatically generate pop ads of tradeadexchange.com . I have tried many possible solutions but none of them worked.

In head tag, this script is automatically injected.
[image]

Below calls are created. In chrome console>Network> 
[image]

How should I remove this script tag in my code in wordpress. Site link -http://www.radhefurnishing.com

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not an issue of wordpress there may be some extension in browser will cause this issue first of all try to check in different browser and different machine.

If that is still there then let me know i will help you using some coding stuff.

Comment: It is not browser problem. Tried in Chrome, Edge and mobile browser. Also checked in other device.

Comment: Then find a script from where this is inserted, generally this is using function   wp_enqueue_script and for adding into head a function wp_head hook is used so , this is just for information so you can find it easily.